# How do I output XML as a string from an XmlTextReader into a Response.Write?

Tags: asp.net, xmltextreader

I have retrieved some XML from an API (at least I think so, the server response is 'OK') however I am putting the response stream into an XmlTextReader, how do I output this XML as a string?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try [XmlTextReader.ReadOuterXml().](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.readouterxml.aspx)

Comment: Just a note.  This can not be used to debug input since it can not read with invalid XML :)